# Column width with jQuery

Tags: jquery, column

ms-vh2 exists by verifying "view source" but I cant get the following code to do the tricks for me. any idea??

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $("tr.ms-viewheadertr th:contains('Name')").css("width", "315px");
    //$("TH.ms-vh2:contains('Name')").css("width", "50px");
    //$("TH.ms-vh2-nograd:contains('Title')").css("width", "350px");
    //$("TH.ms-vh2:contains('LongDescription')").css("width", "350px");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is working for me.  Try this to see if the selector is working for you:

```
$("th.ms-vh2:contains('Name')").css("background-color", "red");
```

It might be that your selector is working, but the css ***seems*** like it isn't.  What I mean by this is that I can't reduce the width of the <th> to 1px because the content that it contains won't allow it to be that small.

Comment: Red background works. However, no matter what i put 1px or 1000 px it does not change. i think ootb css overwrites the width piece.

Comment: I guess Marc is right . http://www.endusersharepoint.com/STP/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=959
You're adjusting the table header cell (TH), but not the table detail cells (TDs) below them. The widest cell usually wins.

Comment: I was able to adjust the width, but was not able to make it that small.  Check out this article. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saurabhkv/archive/2009/06/22/javascript-pageload-add-function.aspx You can use the _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push method to ensure the body of the document has loaded before your JQuery runs.

Comment: I thank you for trying this for me and find a solution. But this did not work for me. <script language="javascript">   
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("FunctionName");   
    function FunctionName()   
    {   
        // Code   
    }   
</script>

Comment: Actually, I turned on the developer tools for IE and I get an error on this line _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('ColumnWidth'); I tried _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("ColumnWidth"); but same error

Comment: Check this out.  It may help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointcustomization/thread/c5c36734-b098-45a4-adf5-703fdc77e43d

Comment: You may need to add a references to SharePoint's javascript libraries: <script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js" type="text/javascript" onload="null"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.js" type="text/javascript" onload="null"></script>

Comment: I needed a `setTimeout()`.